# Rogue EAP (PEAP) access point to obtain hashes

Tags: wifi, peap

I set up a rogue EAP access point using [hostapd-mana](https://github.com/sensepost/mana). This lets me capture hashes of credentials which can later be cracked by [asleap](http://www.willhackforsushi.com/?page_id=41). However, my Android phone doesn't automatically connect to my (rogue) AP even though the SSID is the same and the rogue AP's signal strength is better than the legitimate access point. Why?

Comment: Clients do not connect by SSID, but by BSSID (MAC). The SSID is only a human thing :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few factors you need to have in mind when you want a "supplicant" to connect to an AP automatically. (This is called [WiFi roaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi#Multiple_access_points))

If you want to set a [Rogue AP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_access_point) or an [Evil Twin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_twin_(wireless_networks)) (which aren't the same) to steal credentials and/or capture packets, here's the checklist:

- **Signal Strength** (Make sure your rogue AP signal is higher than the legitimate AP)
- **ESSID** (What probe requests look for)
- **Encryption algorithm** (Open, WEP, WPA, etc.)
- **Cipher** (CCMP, TKIP, WEP40, etc.)

Check all these and your device/supplicant should be able to connect automatically.

Comment: Well said @Azteca